# pass user input list as argument to function, use arguments to call other functions

Tags: python, input

I have some functions to print letters in a 7x7 grid. I have another function that puts those patterns together side by side.

What  I would like to do is: ask for user input, store it as a list, for example ['L', 'O', 'T']

then somehow use those list items to call the existing functions for each letter pattern and print together.

an example of a letter pattern:

```
def L():
    str="";    
    for Row in range(0,7):    
        for Col in range(0,7):     
            if (Col == 1 or (Row == 6 and Col != 0 and Col < 6)):  
                str=str+"*"    
            else:      
                str=str+" "    
        str=str+"\n"    
    return str
```

then user input:

```
u_input=input("input chosen letters: ")
let = list(uinput)
```

function to display multiple letters side by side:

```
def word(a,b,c):
    print('\n'.join(''.join(l) for l in zip(a.split('\n'), b.split('\n'), c.split('\n'))))
```

I just can't figure out how to map that user input into the word function. Would appreciate any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying you have a function L which you want to be called when the user inputs "L"? That's a good use for a dictionary.

```
function_dict={"L":L,"O":O,"T":T}
u_input=input("input chosen letters: ")
let = list(uinput)
for letter in let:
    function_dict[letter]()
```

Comment: If a user enters say LOT. I want my word() function to somehow call the 3 (or more) separate patterns to display those letters together.

Comment: the last line works to print letters vertically which is great! just need to print horizontally now

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eval()` to evaluate a string into any python code you want.

```
u_input=input("input chosen letters: ")
let = list(u_input)
print(let)
```

Result:

`['L', 'O', 'T']`

```
def word(listofletters):
    print("".join(listofletters))
word(let)
```

Result:

`LOT`

```
for letter in let:
    print(eval(letter+"()"))
```

Result:

```
 *
 *
 *
 *
 *
 *
 *****
```

Etc.